# How to make a draggable handle (div) in a scrubber bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create and audio scrubber bar using a handle I can drag back and forth to a different part of the music.

The item that has to be draggable is the `.handle`, and `.played` will follow it.

I made the structure as below: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gvkacym1/)

```css
.scrubber {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.scrubber>.bar {
  background: transparent;
  height: 10px;
}

.scrubber>.buffer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: 0;
}

.scrubber>.played {
  position: absolute;
  width:100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  
}

.scrubber>.played>.handle {
  float: right;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="scrubber">
  <div class="bar"></div>

  <div class="buffer"></div>
  <div class="played">
    <div class="handle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
<input type="range" />
```

and stylize it as you need

codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MLZpzg